# Save dynamically created dropdownlist and textbox value to database using asp.net and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a dropdownbox and textboxes using jQuery I am creating them dynamically

```
<table id="input" border="0" align="center" style="width: 55%">
<tr>
<td width="20%" align="left"><strong>Item Name</strong></td>
<td width="20%" align="left"><strong>Price</strong></td>
<td width="20%" align="left"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
<td width="20%" align="left"><strong>Total</strong></td>
<td width="20%" align="left"><strong>Action</strong></td>
 </tr>
<tr class="input_fields_nominee" >
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustomers1" runat="server" Height="16px" name="ddlCustomers1[]" onchange="get_Price(this.id)" Width="156px">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="TxtPrice1" calss="txtSalesPerson" name="TxtPrice1[]" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="Txtquantity1" runat="server" name="Txtquantity1[]" onkeyup="set_total_price(this.id)" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="TxtTotal1" name="TxtTotal1[]" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>                             
<td>
<input type="button" value="Add"  id="btn_add1" class="add_field_button_nominee" />&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Remove" id="btn_remove1" class="remove_field_nominee" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

To create them dynamically I am using jQuery script is given below

```
$(window).load(function () {
var max_nominee = 21; //maximum input nominee allowed
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
//--------------------------//
if (x < max_nominee) {
$(".add_field_button_nominee").live('click', function () {                           
var $tr = $(this).closest('.input_fields_nominee');
var $clone = $tr.clone();
$clone.find(':text').val('');
$clone.find('*').each(function (index, element)
{
var ele_id = element.id;
$('#' + ele_id).attr("id", ele_id + x);
});
$tr.after($clone);
x++;
});
}
});
```

On page load
[image]

when I click the add button, a row is created dynamically

[image]

Now I want to save those values to a SQL Server database.

Comment: Well - when you've created the fields dynamically via javascript - I think your only choices are to submit the form and then bind the values - likely via Request.Form and then save the data from there.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen can you give me any sample or link which can help me to do this.

Comment: It's just the basic Form stuff: for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx